# Content filter in WordPress removes <h1> tags, among other things

Tags: html, wordpress

When displaying post content in my custom WordPress theme, I found that `$post->post_content` wasn't keeping any of the carriage returns or formatting, so I looked to the `the_content` filter:

```php
<?php echo apply_filter('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>
```

I'll admit that I'm still getting my head around the hooks in WordPress, and that I'm yet to find a really good tutorial on understanding them, but this approach to treating my text has very unexpected results. For example, it keeps the `<p>` tags that are inserted automatically in the WordPress Text Editor Wysiwyg, but it doesn't add any `<h1>` tags. Stranger still, within the actual Wysiwyg, when I flip over to the HTML, it seems to ignore the `<p>` tags.

Having written the text in the Wysiwyg, and given the top line a format of Heading1 from the drop-down menu, here is what the HTML tab of the Wysiwyg shows:

```html
<h1>Text Heading</h1>
An example paragraph.
```

And here's what actually prints out to the site using `the_content` hook filter:

```html
Text Heading
<p>An example paragraph.</p>
```

Needless to say, this behaviour is making it very difficult to style the text. Is this expected behaviour to seasoned WordPress developers?